# Include JavaDB into .jar file (Netbeans)

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, javadb

I have finally finished my project - a small multiple-choice/vocabulary trainer and I'd like to use it as a standalone jar now.
Problem now is: If I do start it within the build-folder (projectname/dist) everything runs fine.
But when I try to run it from somewhere else I can't connect to the database anymore.

Is there a way to include the DB-files to the .jar file? Or to just copy it to the same folder? Or do I need to have JavaDB installed on the PC's I run it on?

This is the way I do connect to the db:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DataBase");
stmt = con.createStatement();
```

So is there any chance I can create a portable app of this, which I can run eg from an usb-stick?

Comment: "I can't connect", you'll have to elaborate on that.

Comment: I do get a classNotFoundExeption for the org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
So it's not the missing database, it is the driver?

Comment: Yea, you need to include the driver in the classpath.

Comment: I found these links: https://www.google.it/search?client=firefox-b&dcr=0&q=embedded+derby+database+in+jar&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjizsqlofvXAhUHWRQKHSC4CYYQvwUIJCgA&biw=1536&bih=723

Answer (score 0):

You do not install JavaDB. However, it will create files, if you tell it to, that hold your DB info. Look at the create=yes option on the JDBC URL. You will have to tell it where to put the files for the DB. They could be on a USB, as long as it is writable.